# Como desabilitar y habiliar boton en jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, web, datatables

Tengo un problema, necesito que se **deshabilite** el `botón` cuando agrego un articulo a la tabla temporal y cuando **elimine** el articulo de la tabla volver a **activarlo**, me pueden ayudar con eso. Estoy trabajando con **datatable** y los artículos los listo desde la `base de datos` mediante una `ventana modal`.

Agrego el `código`:

> **funcion agregar detalle js los cuales traigo de productos registrados en la base de datos**

```
var cont=0; var detalles=0;

function agregarDetalle(idarticulos,nombre,stock)
{
  var cantidad=1;

  if (idarticulos!="")
  {


$('#btnagrega_articulo').prop('disabled', true);
     

     var subtotal=cantidad;
     var fila='<tr class="filas" id="fila'+cont+'">'+
    '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminarDetalle('+cont+')">X</button</td>'+
    '<td><input type="hidden" name="idarticulos[]" value="'+idarticulos+'">'+nombre+'</td>'+
    
    '<td><input type="hidden" name="stock[]" value='+stock+'>'+stock+'</td>'+
    '<td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad[]" value="'+cantidad+'"></td>'+
    '<td><span name="subtotal" id="subtotal'+cont+'">'+subtotal+'</span></td>'+
    '</tr>';
    cont++;
    detalles=detalles+1;
    $('#detalles').append(fila);
    
}
else
{

}
```

> **funcion que elima los articulos de la tabla temporal**

```
function eliminarDetalle(indice){
  $("#fila"+indice).remove();
$('#btnagrega_articulo').prop('disabled', false);

  detalles=detalles-1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dependiendo de donde quieras **habilitar** y **deshabilitar** tu `botón`, usa esta instrucción de `jQuery`:

En caso de querer **deshabilitarlo**:

```
 $('#miBoton').prop('disabled', true);
```

En caso de querer **habilitarlo**:

```
 $('#miBoton').prop('disabled', false);
```

Por lo que veo, puedo notar que usas `Bootstrap`, por lo tanto eso te servirá. Pruébalo.

> **Actualización**

De acuerdo al `código` y a la `lógica` que desarrollaste en el mismo, adapté lo mejor posible el código a tu `lógica` *(hay formas más fáciles y entendibles de realizarlo)*.

**NOTA: Antes de cambiar tu código por este, comenta el original para evitar conflictos.**

En **primer paso**, debes cambiar a `class` en lugar de `id` de tu botón `btnagrega_articulo`, adjunto ejemplo:

```
while ($reg=$rspta->fetch_object()){
    $data[]=array(
        "0"=>'<button class="btn btn-warning btnagrega_articulo" onclick="agregarDetalle('.$reg->idarticulos.',\''.$reg->nombre_arti.'\',\''.$reg->marca_arti.'\',\''.$reg->modelo_arti.'\',\''.$reg->codigo_arti.'\',\''.$reg->stock.'\')"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button>',
        "1"=>$reg->nombre_arti,
        "2"=>$reg->marca_arti,
        "3"=>$reg->modelo_arti,
        "4"=>$reg->categoria,
        "5"=>$reg->codigo_arti,
        "6"=>$reg->stock,
        
        );
   }
```

**Segundo paso**, la `variable` **fila** que construye la `tabla temporal` se declara fuera para poder acceder a ella desde cualquier `método`, posteriromente se declara la `variable` **identificador_articulo**, la cual es el punto clave para realizar la tarea que solicitaste.

Después se **modificó** tu `método` **agregaDetalle** para que únicamente deje listo el artículo listo en la `variable` **fila**.

Y finalmente se realizó un evento `click` para la `clase` del `botón` **btnagrega_articulo**, el cual procede a realizar el llenado de la `tabla temporal`, bloquea el `botón` y agrega una nueva `clase` la cual servirá para su posterior desbloqueo.

Este sería el `código` nuevo:

```
    var fila = "";
    var identificador_articulo = 0;

    //Solo dejará listo el artículo que se va a agregar a la otra tabla
    function agregarDetalle(idarticulos,nombre_arti,marca_arti,modelo_arti,codigo_arti,stock){

        var cantidad = 1;

            if(idarticulos != ""){

                var subtotal = cantidad;
                identificador_articulo = idarticulos;

                fila ='<tr class="filas" data-id="aux'+idarticulos+'" id="fila'+cont+'">'+
                    '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminarDetalle('+cont+')">X</button</td>'+
                    '<td><input type="hidden" name="idarticulos[]" value="'+idarticulos+'">'+nombre_arti+'</td>'+
                    '<td><input type="hidden" name="marca" value='+marca_arti+'>'+marca_arti+'</td>'+
                    '<td><input type="hidden" name="modelo" value='+modelo_arti+'>'+modelo_arti+'</td>'+
                    '<td><input type="hidden" name="codigo" value='+codigo_arti+'>'+codigo_arti+'</td>'+
                    '<td><input type="hidden" name="stock[]" value='+stock+'>'+stock+'</td>'+
                    '<td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad[]" value="'+cantidad+'"></td>'+
                    '<td><span name="subtotal" id="subtotal'+cont+'">'+subtotal+'</span></td>'+
                    '</tr>';                    

            }else{

                alert("Error al ingresar el detalle, revisar los datos del artículo");
            }

    }


    $('.btnagrega_articulo').click(function(){

        if(fila != ""){

            $(this).addClass('aux'+ identificador_articulo);
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);             

            cont++;
            detalles = detalles + 1;
            $('#detalles').append(fila);
            modificarSubtotales();
        }
        
    });
```

Y como **último paso**, se modificó la `función` **eliminarDetalle** para que al momento de **eliminar** el artículo, se vuelva a **habilitar** el `botón` respectivo de la `tabla principal`.

```
function eliminarDetalle(indice){

        $("#fila"+indice).remove();
        var desbloquea_btn = $('#fila'+indice).data('id');

        $('.'+desbloquea_btn).prop('disabled', false);
        $('.'+desbloquea_btn).removeClass('.'+desbloquea_btn);

        calcularTotales();
        detalles=detalles-1;
    }
```

Pruébalo, y si resolvió tu problema marca como respuesta correcta, saludos.

Comment: Hola, si me deshabilita pero al momento de elegir otro producto no lo hace y si elimino del detalle otro producto que no sea el agregue al detalle igual lo habilita, cuando no estoy quitando el que agregue previamente

Comment: @pedroruiz Incluye imágenes en tu pregunta sobre tu interfaz explicando detalladamente qué es lo que quieres lograr, ya que solo platicándolo no sabremos cómo ayudarte. Viendo la interfaz junto con el código es más fácil saber qué es lo que quieres realizar.

Comment: Agregue las imagenes, lo que necesito es que al seleccionar el boton de x producto se desabilite cuando se agregue a la tabla temporal y luego si lo elimino de la tabla temporal habilitar ese boton de ese articulo

Comment: @pedroruiz ok, ahora como se llama el identificador o clase que le asignaste a ese botón?

Comment: id="btnagrega_articulo"

Comment: @pedroruiz como mandas llamar la función `agregarDetalle`? ya casi tengo la solución, pero quiero saber eso.. y también de una vez cómo mandas llamar la función `eliminarDetalle`

Comment: Con onclick al momento de listar y recibe varios parámetros, puedes ver claramente en la case que lista los artículos registrados en la base de datos

Comment: recibe idarticulos,modelo_arti, marca_arti,codigo_arti,nombre arti y stock

Comment: el de eliminar se llama en la tabla que se va llenando es un td dentro de tr fila, también se hace el llamado con onclick

Comment: @pedroruiz actualicé la respuesta, léelo y pruébalo. Tardé un poco porque estaba adaptando el nuevo código a tu lógica...

Comment: Hola, hice el arreglo pero no agrega articulos a la tabla detalle

Comment: antes de declara la funcion agregar detalle declaro la variable cont y detalles inicializadas en cero